# Failed to create provisioner: Failed to initialize file readers: type is not supported

Tags: grafana

i am trying to provision a grafana dashboard.

the log says:

```
lvl=eror msg="Failed to provision dashboard" logger=provisioning error="Failed to create provisioner: Failed to initialize file readers: type is not supported"
lvl=eror msg="Stopped provisioningServiceImpl" logger=server reason="Failed to create provisioner: Failed to initialize file readers: type is not supported"
```

i am trying to privision `My Shiny new Dashboard-1597735961598.json` (Standard Dashboard)

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "gnetId": null,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": 1,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Microsoft SQL Server",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "custom": {}
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "fill": 1,
      "fillGradient": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 9,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "hiddenSeries": false,
      "id": 2,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "options": {
        "dataLinks": []
      },
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "alias": "",
          "format": "time_series",
          "rawSql": "SELECT\n  $__timeEpoch(<time_column>),\n  <value column> as value,\n  <series name column> as metric\nFROM\n  <table name>\nWHERE\n  $__timeFilter(time_column)\nORDER BY\n  <time_column> ASC",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "Panel Title",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 0,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "schemaVersion": 25,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [],
  "templating": {
    "list": []
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-6h",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {
    "refresh_intervals": [
      "10s",
      "30s",
      "1m",
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "30m",
      "1h",
      "2h",
      "1d"
    ]
  },
  "timezone": "",
  "title": "My Shiny new Dashboard",
  "uid": "HHaYthIGk",
  "version": 2
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after struggling a bit i found out the the error was caused by a missing entry `type: file`

```
apiVersion: 1

providers:
  - name: 'Default'
    type: file <-- i was missing this line 
    options:
      path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
```

i was assuming that this is a default as written in the
[docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/)

Comment: Older version have this entry required, for example https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.5/administration/provisioning/